# при экспорте и импорте postgres не видит директорию либо сам csv файл

Tags: postgresql, csv

При попытке импортировать или экспортировать csv файл Postgres не видит директорию или не распознает сам csv файл. Настройки безопасности самого csv файла в порядке. Подскажите, плиз, в чем проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: как именно делаете эти операции? Если через cli добавьте в вопрос команды.

Comment: я делаю эти операции при помощи скрипта такоко например   copy actor to 'C:\Users\ПК\Desktop\actor_202310212134.csv"'
with (format csv, header,delimiter ',', encoding'win1251')   Также пытался сделать операцию через интерфейс, результат  тот же: : No such file or directory

Comment: Команда COPY TO в PostgreSQL выполняется сервером, а не клиентом. Файлы, указанные в команде COPY, читаются или записываются непосредственно сервером, а не клиентским приложением. Поэтому они должны располагаться на сервере или быть доступными серверу, а не клиенту. Они должны быть доступны на чтение или запись пользователю PostgreSQL. Судя по представленным вами обрывочным данным вы используете PostgreSQL для Windows где он работает с правами сетевой службы и не имеет доступа в профили пользователей.

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо! У меня PostgresSQL действительно установлен на Windows , думаю вы правы!